# How to encode a byte array to sound file and then convert back?

Tags: matlab, digital-communications

This question is moved from Stack Overflow.

Sorry about this noob question, because I never work with matlab and signal processing before. Here is what I want to do: I have a fixed length of byte array X, now I want to encode it to a sound file, I also want this process to be reversible, which means the sound can be converted back to X with no error. I searched online, and found the following code:

```
M = 16; 
x = randint(5000,1,M); 
y=modulate(modem.qammod(M),x);
```

My question is that, is QAM the best way to do this? and how to use it? I will need to send the sound signal over the air, and I just need to transfer about 128 bit data each time. A little bit code example will be really appreciated, Thank you!

update#1: I tried to output y by sound(y), but matlab does not allow me to do so, it says I can only output floating numbers. How can I solve this? Thank you!

Comment: Could you please tell us more about your application? For example, should it be possible to play the audio file on speakers, record it with another device, and decode the data from the other device? If so, this is a digital communication problem (for which techniques like QAM are indeed relevant), and you'll need to characterize the channel (what kind of operations/degradations will happen between emitter and receiver?). If this is not what you are trying to do, explain your application more clearly.

Comment: Are you saying you want to implement a voiceband modem.  If so, QAM is a reasonable approach.  The "best" modulation scheme depends on the characteristics of your channel (background noise, distortion, frequency response etc).